# How to change the IEEETran.bst file to ignore the months in the date?

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I am wirting my thesis with Lyx, and BibTex for creating my Bibliography. My .bib is generated by Mendeley. So, what I try to manage is to find a way to change my IEEEtran.bst style file to ignore the months for the BibTeX.

At the moment the output includes the month and the year of publishing:

**..., dec 2017**

But I need to remove the months for each entry. As the `.bib` file is generated by Mendeley, changing it does not work for me. Also deleting the months manually is also not working, as Mendeley automatically updates these information.

The Function for the date in the IEEETran file looks like that:

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{
  month "month" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
  year  "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    { swap$ 'skip$
        { this.to.prev.status
          this.status.std
          cap.status.std
         "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$ }
      if$
      *
    }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.status.std
      swap$ 'skip$
        {
          swap$
          " " * swap$
        }
      if$
      *
    }
  if$
}
```

The problem is that I do not really know what to change that the month will be ignored. I tried many possible combinations of deleting parts. But I still cannot find a solution...
Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use a moth repellent ;o)

Comment: Would be great!! Where to buy? ;) And Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `@article`, `format.date` has to be changed like this:

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{
  "" duplicate$ empty$
  year  "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    { swap$ 'skip$
        { this.to.prev.status
          this.status.std
          cap.status.std
         "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$ }
      if$
      *
    }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.status.std
      swap$ 'skip$
        {
          swap$
          " " * swap$
        }
      if$
      *
    }
  if$
}
```

and for `@inproceedings`, `format.address.org.or.pub.date` has to be modified.

```
FUNCTION {format.address.org.or.pub.date}
{ 't :=
  ""
  year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { skip$ }
  if$
  address empty$ t empty$ and
  year empty$ and month empty$ and
    { skip$ }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.status.std
      address "address" bibinfo.check *
      t empty$
        { skip$ }
        { punct.period 'prev.status.punct :=
          space.large 'prev.status.space :=
          address empty$
            { skip$ }
            { ": " * }
          if$
          t *
        }
      if$
      year empty$ month empty$ and
        { skip$ }
        { t empty$ address empty$ and
            { skip$ }
            { ", " * }
          if$
          month empty$
            { year empty$
                { skip$ }
                { year "year" bibinfo.check * }
              if$
            }
            { year empty$
                 { skip$ }
                 { " " * year "year" bibinfo.check * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@article{fuext1,
    year={2004},
    month={May},
    booktitle={$23^{rd}$ International Conference on the Theory and Applications of Cryptographic Techniques (EUROCRYPT)},
    volume={3027},
    title={Fuzzy Extractors: How to Generate Strong Keys from Biometrics and Other Noisy Data},
    publisher={{LNCS}, Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
    author={Dodis, Yevgeniy and Reyzin, Leonid and Smith, Adam},
    address={Interlaken, Switzerland},
    pages={523-540},
}

@inproceedings{fuext2,
    year={2004},
    month={May},
    booktitle={$23^{rd}$ International Conference on the Theory and Applications of Cryptographic Techniques (EUROCRYPT)},
    volume={3027},
    title={Fuzzy Extractors: How to Generate Strong Keys from Biometrics and Other Noisy Data},
    author={Dodiz, Yevgeniy and Reyzin, Leonid and Smith, Adam},
    address={Interlaken, Switzerland, {LNCS}, Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
    pages={523-540},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Article \cite{fuext1} and Proceedings \cite{fuext2}.
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot. This helped me a lot! Hope this also helps some other "lost" people :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Richard you can make one of the answer as 'accepted answer'.

Answer (score 0):

BibTeX syntax can be rather confusing - the easiest solution is sometimes to copy a function from a more basic bibliography style with simpler syntax.

The following is modified from `abbrvnat.bst`:

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year  "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$
       pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
```

Note that `IEEEtran.bst` uses a separate date formatting function for `inproceedings` entries, so this should be edited as well:

```
FUNCTION {format.address.org.or.pub.date}
{ 't :=
  ""
  year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { skip$ }
  if$
  address empty$ t empty$ and
  year empty$ and month empty$ and
    { skip$ }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.status.std
      address "address" bibinfo.check *
      t empty$
        { skip$ }
        { punct.period 'prev.status.punct :=
          space.large 'prev.status.space :=
          address empty$
            { skip$ }
            { ": " * }
          if$
          t *
        }
      if$
      year empty$ month empty$ and
        { skip$ }
        { t empty$ address empty$ and
            { skip$ }
            { ", " * }
          if$
          month empty$
            { year empty$
                { skip$ }
                { year "year" bibinfo.check * }
              if$
            }
            { year empty$ % removed printing the month string here
                 { skip$ }
                 { " " * year "year" bibinfo.check * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

MWE using the modified `IEEEtran.bst`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{articlemonth,
  author = {Mary Jones},
  title = {First Things},
  journal = {Journal of Things},
  month = {jan},
  year = {2017}
}

@inproceedings{proceedingsmonth,
  author = {Joe Peterson},
  title = {Briefly Explained},
  booktitle = {Conference of Briefness},
  month = {feb},
  year = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
See \cite{articlemonth,proceedingsmonth}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranmod}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]